# Passing data from UIViewController to a UIPopover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UITableView` whose custom cells are populated with `NSManagedObjects`. I've configured a button on my custom cells to display a popover when selected.

I initially tried implementing a popover using `performSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegue`, but UIPopover segues don't seem to like dynamic content from UITableViews. Instantiating the popover via `self.presentViewController` is working for me, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to pass data to it.

```
func demoButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {        
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("demoPopover")
    vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    vc?.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.width * 0.75, tableView.bounds.height * 0.75)


    if let presentationController = vc?.popoverPresentationController {
        presentationController.delegate = self
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        // sender is a UIButton on a custom cell
        presentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.origin.x, tableView.bounds.origin.y, sender.bounds.width, sender.bounds.height / 2)

        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here's how I plan to get a hold of the object I'd like to pass to the popover's ViewController.

```
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview
    let cell = view?.superview as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    let myObjectIWantToPass = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNSManagedObject
```

How would I get my object from the `ViewController` to `PopoverViewController`? Should I be passing the object or is there another route I should be going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not doing much besides passing the object one way, I ended up using `NSUserDefaults` to pass it. I found these answers helpful:

[Passing data between segues without using PrepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877130/passing-data-between-segues-without-using-prepareforsegue)

```
func demoButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {        
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("demoPopover")
    vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    vc?.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.bounds.width * 0.75, tableView.bounds.height * 0.75)

    // Get a hold of the managedObject I want to access from the popoverVC
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview
    let cell = view?.superview as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    let myObjectIWantToPass = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyNSManagedObject

                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myObjectIWantToPass.attribute, forKey: "objectToDemoAttribute")

    if let presentationController = vc?.popoverPresentationController {
        presentationController.delegate = self
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        // sender is a UIButton on a custom cell
        presentationController.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.origin.x, tableView.bounds.origin.y, sender.bounds.width, sender.bounds.height / 2)

        self.presentViewController(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` of my `popoverVC`, I access `NSUserDefaults` to set labels, etc. on the popOver.

You cannot pass `NSManagedObjects` via `NSUserDefaults`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19720674/4475605) got me squared away on that front.

> You can only store things like NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString,
>   NSData, NSNumber, and NSDate in NSUserDefaults.

For my purposes, I can get away with passing attributes from my `NSManagedObject` because they're only going one way.